# How to land accurately with a plane?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've created a basic sub-orbital plane in KSP, it flies well enough. On landing, I always cut the engines, then go into a glide from ~6km up then end up overshooting the runway or landing to it's side. Also, sometimes my plane will glide up when I'm pitching it up for landing.

How can I land straight on the runway? Do I need to angle the glide further down or do something else?

Comment: The best way? Fly quite slowly above the runway, then cut the engines and deploy all the parachutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I try to avoid it is by trying to glide the last kilometer (or so) on approach close to the ground (100-200m above the terrain).

Don't just nosedive towards the beginning of the runway and then flare up close to the ground.
The problem with such a quick descent is that you pick up speed while doing so. Because you pick up speed, two things happen:

- It's less accurate to flare up when you want to. Since you're going faster, you're less accurate in pinpointing the place to do it. Because you're more afraid of smashing into the ground, you'll generally try to stay on the safe side, which means you will overshoot.
- Because you're going faster *and* because you're descending in to the lower part of the atmosphere, your wings generate more lift, meaning you glide a lot longer. Since you started the descent with less lift, you also gauged how to approach it based on your current situation, not the amount of lift you'll have after descending quickly. This again leads to you overshooting.

I actually learned this from War Thunder. Completely different game, but it teaches you to land a plane very realistically, and has a decent tutorial on basic maneuvers including landing. If you want to learn how to fly planes better intuitively, you might want to check it out (it's free to play, and a very good flight sim in my opinion).

If your plane either still has plenty of fuel, or can glide with ease, I'd always opt for maybe even just flying a round around KSC to bleed off speed.
If you can't afford that (out of fuel), another option to bleed off speed is by "wagging" your tail (yawing left/right to create more drag).

Comment: Thanks, this looks like good advice but how can I know if I'm 1 km out?

Comment: Well it was just an estimated number. "Well ahead". it's not a precise measurement. ALthough, some people e.g. plant flags at either end of the runway so they can use the markers to line up their approach with the runway. You can then also use those markers to gauge distance to the runway (I assume you also get distance markers for flags, just like for craft? Not 100% sure)